# Which alternative to use instead of document.write()?

Tags: javascript, html, tampermonkey

So guys, I made a little script to put in Tampermonkey for my presentations, but I have a problem.

What I want is to swap document.write(), but I don't know which function I could swap to replace it so that it leaves the code cleaner and more organized.

Besides document.write() is also not considered a good programming practice.

Comment: The easiest way for me is to use jQuery and use this kind of function :
`$('#item_with_an_id").html(variable_of_content_to_put_inside)`

Comment: Learn [DOM Manipulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction).

Comment: Alternatives: 1.)  Use AJAX to replace DOM objects. 2.) take a look at the new <template> tag (create custom html elements) and how to use it. Even if you use document.write it will becomes in this case a single liner. and BTW: forget about good prcatices - a good praxis is to get something to work not to fiddle around endless by homebrewed problems of other peoples. ;) doc write is not that elegant, but its there since decades, simple and do the job (And best of  - you know how to use it). Have fun ! .)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to come up with your own function. But before taking any action, you need to think that there must be a injection into document body. You can try to use

document.body.appendChild()

and inside off that method, you can have some kind of html code.
Other than that you must generate a html document by using document.createDocumentFragment() or document.createElements().

Comment: document.body.appendChild() not document.appendChild()

Comment: `.appendChild()` takes a Node, not `.innerHTML`. Use `document.createElement()` to create an Element, then just assign properties with the dot syntax, before using `AnyNode.appendChild(Node)`. `document.createElements()` is not a function.